# select from two tables each with different join

Tags: mysql

Trying to run this query will not return any error but I guess there is still something wrong in it. After four minutes running it keeps elaborating:

```
SELECT DISTINCT azioni_row.id_az, sofferenze.Descrizione, COUNT(crediti.stato = 'aperta') as aperti, COUNT(crediti.stato = 'chiusa') as chiusi
FROM (`azioni_row`, sofferenze) 
JOIN crediti ON azioni_row.id_cred=crediti.id_cre 
JOIN azioni_head as ah1 ON azioni_row.id_az=ah1.id_az
JOIN azioni_head as ah2 ON ah2.id_soff = sofferenze.id_soff
GROUP BY id_az  
ORDER BY `azioni_row`.`id_az` ASC
```

If I remove sofferenze.Descrizione from the select list and sofferenze from the FROM list it runs in a few seconds:

```
SELECT DISTINCT azioni_row.id_az, COUNT(crediti.stato = 'aperta') as aperti, COUNT(crediti.stato = 'chiusa') as chiusi
FROM azioni_row 
JOIN crediti ON azioni_row.id_cred=crediti.id_cre 
JOIN azioni_head as ah1 ON azioni_row.id_az=ah1.id_az
GROUP BY id_az  
ORDER BY `azioni_row`.`id_az` ASC
```

I would like to show the Descrizione field but the link for it is in the head table, not in the row one. The relationship between head and row is a one to many. I store in head all the info that is not necessary to repeat for each row and the link with Descrizione is one of these fields.

EDIT:
this is the explain:
[image]

this is the create for azioni_head:

```
CREATE TABLE `azioni_head` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `tipo` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 `id_az` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `id_soff` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `id_soff_gar` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `date_from` date NOT NULL,
 `date_to` date NOT NULL,
 `close_why` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `RGE` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `procedente` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 `curatore` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `legale` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `tribunale` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `riparto` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `perc_worst` decimal(13,10) NOT NULL,
 `perc_best` decimal(13,10) NOT NULL,
 `perc_poster` decimal(13,10) NOT NULL,
 `attivo_storico` decimal(65,2) NOT NULL,
 `passivo_storico` decimal(65,2) NOT NULL,
 `attivo_storico_comm` decimal(65,2) NOT NULL,
 `passivo_storico_comm` decimal(65,2) NOT NULL,
 `acconti` decimal(65,2) NOT NULL,
 `acconti_comm` decimal(65,2) NOT NULL,
 `numero_comm` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `legali_worst` decimal(65,2) NOT NULL,
 `legali_best` decimal(65,2) NOT NULL,
 `manuale` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1449 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='tabella testata azioni'
```

this for azioni_row:

```
CREATE TABLE `azioni_row` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_az` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `id_cred` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `chiesto` decimal(65,2) NOT NULL,
 `ammesso` decimal(65,2) NOT NULL,
 `data_ammesso` date NOT NULL,
 `rango_ammesso` tinytext NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4479 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and this for sofferenze

```
CREATE TABLE `sofferenze` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_soff` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `Descrizione` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `gruppo` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `cointestazione` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `port_man` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `head_port_man` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `note` longtext NOT NULL,
 `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_3` (`id`),
 KEY `id_2` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1716 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, I don't get what you mean. is DISTINCT() not a valid syntax? The second query returns the same results even without ()

Comment: no. it doesn't. row match with head and in head there is the only field that match with sofferenze

Comment: ah1 and ah2 are the same table. I defined two different alias to get rid of the azioni_head being a not unique table without

Comment: I was thinking about creating a table from the query in the second version and then apply the last join on this temporary table. Is this a crazy option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide proper CREATE statements as well as the output of:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT a.id_az
     , s.Descrizione
     , COUNT(c.stato = 'aperta') aperti
     , COUNT(c.stato = 'chiusa') chiusi
  FROM azioni_row a
  JOIN sofferenze s
 CROSS
  JOIN crediti c
    ON c.id_cre = a.id_cred
  JOIN azioni_head ah1 
    ON ah1.id_az = a.id_az
  JOIN azioni_head ah2 
    ON ah2.id_soff = s.id_soff 
 GROUP 
    BY a.id_az  
     , s.Descrizione
 ORDER 
    BY a.id_az ASC
```

Edit: You seem to have lots of indexes on the same column. Drop all indexes except the PRIMARY KEYs, and create the following indexes:

```
sofferenze: id_soff
azioni_row: try a composite index on (id_az,id_cred)
azioni_head: an index on id_soff and an index on id_az
```

Crediti is missing so I can't comment on that one.